# How to convert (or scale) a FITS image with Astropy

Tags: python, image, scale, astropy, fits

Using the Astropy library, I created a FITS image which is made by interpolation from 2 actual FITS images (they are scaled as "**int16**", the right format for the software I use : Maxim DL).

But **the scale of this image is float64 and not int16**. And any astronomical processing software can't read it (except FITS Liberator)

Do you have an idea how to proceed ? Can we convert a FITS image just by changing the "BITPIX" in the header ?

I tried: (following this method : [Why is an image containing integer data being converted unexpectedly to floats?](http://pyfits.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.0/appendix/faq.html#why-is-an-image-containing-integer-data-being-converted-unexpectedly-to-floats)

```
from astropy.io import fits

hdu1=fits.open('mypicture.fit')
image=hdu1[0]
print(image.header['BITPIX'])  # it gives : -64

image.scale('int16')
data=image.data
data.dtype
print(image.header['BITPIX']) # it gives : 16
hdu1.close()
```

However, when I check the newly-modified scale of "mypicture.fit", **it still displays -64** ! 
No change was saved and applied!

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the image data is a numpy array. Can you not perform the conversion on the array and save as a new .fits file?

Comment: Yes you're right. So, you suggest to create a new .fits file using fits.writeto() ?

Comment: That's what I have done in the past.

Comment: OK. @Jacobadtr : If I well understood, I only add this line at the end of my script : fits.writeto('mypicture_converted.fit',fits.getdata(mypicture.fit'), None, 'ignore')

Comment: But it doesn't work ... The format is still **float64** instead of **int16**

Comment: If it really is just a numpy array, can you use the `astype` operation, as seen [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)?

Comment: I don't have astropy installed on my work computer, but I will take a look when I get home if this has not been resolved.

Comment: @DatHydroGuy : Thanks for the tip. So **astype** allows to convert the float elements of the array into int ? But, it's getting a bit too complicated. I am really an IT specialist, and I wanted to use the power of astropy :)

Comment: I do in fact have astropy installed as it comes with ananconda, I have posted an answer to what I think you're asking....

Comment: Your given code does not work, because you never *write* the changed HDU to disk. You open it in read-only mode, then make some changes, then close the file. You should either save the HDU-list to a (new) file, or open the original file in 'update' mode.

Comment: Your actual problem is thus not how to scale an image, but how to *update* an image on disk.

Comment: Also here `hdu1=fits.open('mypicture.fit')` you're just opening the file in read-only mode.  It's not going to save any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should work.

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np

# create dummy fits file
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]],dtype=np.float64)

hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU()
hdu.data = a

# looking at the header object confirms BITPIX = -64
hdu.header

# change data type
hdu.data = np.int16(hdu.data)

# look again to confirm BITPIX = 16
hdu.header
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jm22b ! The function "np.int16(hdu.data)" is what I was looking for !